# JavaScript to figure out Where a number starts and add a tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am working with 3D carts, they do not give me any access to PHP only JavaScript HTML and CSS. I want to get the dimensions of my products on the category page. but they need to be on a new line so that customers can clearly see it. If i add a `<br />` into the title it messes up a lot of things.

If this was the name of the product I want to find the first number "16" and add a `<br />` in front of it using JavaScript.

```
DELUXE TOTE JR. 16" X 12" X 6"
```

To get the result of

```
DELUXE TOTE JR. <br />
16" X 12" X 6"
```

Is this possible or a lost cause?

Comment: Are the title and dimensions enclosed in the same tag? If so there isn't much chance of doing this. Unless if you can guarantee that no product titles have numbers in them.

Comment: Please show a basic HTML example of your setup.

Comment: I was planning on typing out numbers if they aren't the dementions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript's replace method to accomplish what you want, but like others mentioned, it's going to be tricky if different pieces of that string are wrapped in other elements like spans or divs, or if you don't have a clear selector around the whole string to start with.  If you could post the actual HTML that is output, we could probably get this closer.

```js
var title = document.getElementById('title')
var titleText = title.innerHTML;
var res = titleText.replace(/([0-9]{1,2}")/, "<br/>$&");
title.innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<span id='title'>DELUXE TOTE JR. 16" X 12" X 6"</span>
```

Comment: I will try this out Monday at work, thanks for the reply. I think this will fix my issue.

Comment: I got it to work, But now my problem is I need all the products on the page to do the same thing not just the first one. But the fist one is working properly.

Comment: `function myFunction() {
var title = document.getElementsByClassName("title");



for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 var titleText = title[i].innerHTML;
 var res = titleText.replace(/([0-9]{1,2}")/, "<br/>$&");
 title[i].innerHTML = res;
   }

}` I got it to work with multiple items

Comment: Edward, the example I posted above is for one element with an ID of 'title', so you'd have to change that to whatever matching selector is used for those elements on your page.  If you could post the source code that contains the title and dimensions, we can figure out what that selector should be, then you can apply it to all those elements.

Comment: http://thepackagingteam-com.3dcartstores.com/Tote-Bags_c_53.html# That's what i have so far, the script is the try me button under the menu. The only problem I have is that the decimal numbers aren't being moved down

Comment: I got everything working correctly now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In order for me to get the products on the category page to have the dimensions down a line I had to use the class instead of the id since html doesn't let multiple of the same ids.

JavaScipt

```
var title = document.getElementsByClassName("title");

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var titleText = title[i].innerHTML;
    var res = titleText.replace(/\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/, "<br/>$&");
    title[i].innerHTML = res;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="title">[name]</span>
```

This let me add a `<br/>` before the first number witch is the first dimension.